# Batch saving incrementing file number with an action that has two save steps

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to crop an image into two halves and save both halves with an incrementing page number. I doing this as a batch- it's working OK, however as the Action has two Save steps when I come to run it the second save overwrites the first - the PS file naming number option doesn't increment for both save steps.

So is there a way I can save two files with an incrementing number?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the Slice Tool instead of cropping.

In setting up the action, have the Slice Tool selected as the tool to use.

1. Right-click and select **Divide Slice...**
2. Check "Divide Horizontally (or Vertically depending on flavour) Into..."
3. Enter "**2**" slices down/across evenly spread.
4. Click OK

This will save the actions to slice in half the image clean for exporting the bifurcation.

When you export, the image will be split in twain and the filenames automatically done as thus:

- example_01.jpg
- example_02.jpg

Those representing the two halves of the image.

Comment: Wow thank so much for that great solution and sorry it took me so long to accept it!